# IRT vs proportion/frequency

Tags: histogram, item-response-theory

Let's say I have response data from a multiple choice exam question, and I want to understand whether the item was too difficult or if I should change it somehow to improve it.

What benefits do I get from running a 1PL IRT model vs. just looking at the frequency histogram of the responses?

By looking at the response frequency for each answer option, I can see how many people got the question right (which tells me whether the item was too difficult), which answer options were chosen most infrequently (which tells me it may not be a very good distractor item), etc.

It feels like the histogram would be sufficient for determining whether the question/answer options need to be adjusted. Does IRT provide any additional information that would help me make changes to my question?
I understand that IRT provides information in relation to underlying ability level, so I could use it to ensure that my test questions span a range of latent ability. But besides that, are there any other benefits?